# How to prevent namespace pollution?

Tags: c#

I have a program that defines a class

```
namespace @default
{
    public class Test
    {
    }
}
```

I then referance another library that has no namespaces with a class called `Test`.  How can I hide this other libraries `Test` class so that my program does not see `@default.Test` as the other libraries `Test` class?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but `default` is a reserved word.

Comment: @KendallFrey but `@default` isn't.  You can prefix reserved keywords with an `@` to use them as identifiers.

Comment: I know it's still a poor choice of namespace but it's a code example, not production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, inside your `default` namespace, the `default.Test` class is the one that will be used when you say `Test`.

Outside your `default` namespace, you will need to do something like this in your using statements:

```
using ExternalTest = global::Test;
using Test = default.Test;
```

The first line isn't strictly necessary, as you could use `global::Test` anywhere.

For those that haven't encountered global before: [global (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx).

Comment: Class aliases are great, but if you are the architect of the code, it's much better to plan ahead and avoid them if possible.  I have had many a headache dealing with class conflicts.  Probably shouldn't have created a `Page` class...  Learned from that one.

Comment: @TrueDevelopment I do own both libraries but, my reference is to an old mfc/c++/cli application that we cross compile to to and exe and dll. Fixing it would not be trivial.

Comment: I totally understand.  I have a lot of code I am working with now that has the same issue and it's not worth the time to go back and refactor it all.  Just a suggestion for the future for anyone who might stumble upon this post.  I have learned a lot from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the identifier name with `global::` to indicate that it should be found starting at the global (unnamed) namespace.  For example:

```
class Test { }

namespace Default {
    public class Test {
        global::Test theOtherOne;
    }
}
```

You'll often see it used in auto-generated code to avoid accidental name collisions.  Like Resources.Designer.cs